# Data need to be sorted before merging in R?

Tags: r

I have to merge 2 data files in R based on 3 variable. Is it necessary to sort both the data files by these 3 variables? Or R will be able to merge the files without sorting?

Main Data file:

```
`ID ` var1 var2 var3 Country  Segment Ind
 1     45   1    7      tt      tr      t
 2     55   4   6       gg      hh      h
 3     66   6    8       yy     yt      a
```

The data which have to merge with the  Main data

```
   `ID `  Country  Segment Ind weight
     1      tt      yt      t   0.1
     2      yy      hh      h   0.12
     3      gg      tr      a  0.25
```

Based on Country segment and Ind Weight variable has to merge with the main file.

Thanks,
Tanuvi

Comment: When joining two data frames, sorting isn't an issue, at least insofar as the ability for the join/merge to happen.  Edit your question and please show us sample data and your expected output.

Comment: What precluded you from simply testing it?

Comment: @Roland  I couldn't test is as the data test is very huge,it is not possible to manually check..

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, Thanks, I have edited the question.

Comment: @Tanuvi As the current answer shows, you can always produce a minimal example. I'm quite serious. "Try and test" is an important skill for a programmer. You should not have needed to ask this question.

Comment: @Roland, Thanks for the feedback, I will test it in the future..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

no. you need not sort before merging (that is in SAS not in R)

```
> A1=NULL
> A1$city=c("York","London","Glasgow","Delhi","Atlanta")
> A1$key=1:5
> A1=as.data.frame(A1)
> A1
     city key
1    York   1
2  London   2
3 Glasgow   3
4   Delhi   4
5 Atlanta   5
```

and

```
> B1=NULL
> B1$rent=c("Expensive","Affordable")
> B1$key=c(5,1)
> B1=as.data.frame(B1)
> B1
        rent key
1  Expensive   5
2 Affordable   1
```

merge is very simple in R

```
> merge(A1,B1)
  key    city       rent
1   1    York Affordable
2   5 Atlanta  Expensive
```

Note I didnt have to sort B1 by key

Comment: Thanks, This is very helpful

Comment: also read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1299871/how-to-join-merge-data-frames-inner-outer-left-right?rq=1